# Table Autofill Not Working with Excel data,

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The autofill on Excel tables is not working (for calculations) when I am using a Excel data source (copied & pasted into the file) but is working when I use a CSV data source (copeied & pasted into the file)

I have the 'Fill Formulas in tables to create Calculated columns' ticked

Any ideas?

Comment: Any screenshoots? How do you check if the pasted data is pasted as number/text ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and it seemed to be caused by having the data filters turned on. If you clear the filters at the top, it seems to revert back to the correct auto-fill capabilities.